# text view in android can't be changed

Tags: android

I have `TextView` in my code. I want to test if an `EditText` is empty then fill the `TextView` with "some thing" or take the text from the `EditText`; but it doesn't change the text. Here is the code(in `onCreate()` method):

```
if ((textCity.length())==0){

            cityText.setText("something");

        }
        else

          cityText.setText(textCity);
```

where textCity

```
textCity=editText1.getText();
```

and cityText is the `TextView`

Comment: what exactly is the problem ? does it show any error ? or does it compile normally and shows wrong results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    if (textCity.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                cityText.setText("something");
    }
    else
      cityText.setText(textCity);
```

Comment: Nice. Accept the answer for the benefit of others! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ((textCity.length() < 0)){
   cityText.setText("something");
}
```

textCity=editText1.getText().toString(); //add this when you're grabbing the text from the 
                                         //textview

Comment: Try this when you're getting the text. textCity=editText1.getText().toString(); It first has to be converted to a string for it to recognize it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you haven't invoked it in the right place. You need to place a `TextWatcher` on your `EditText`. Try this out:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        cityText.setText(String.valueOf(s));
    }
});
```